# Global variable to macros

Tags: conditionals

I have a `eskdi.sty` style file where I define two command:

```
\newcommand{\gostorganizatia}[2]{%
  \ifnum #1 = 1% 1 - text; 2 - logo
    \gdef\gostorganizatiaopt{text}%%
    \def\gostorganizatiatext#2{\gdef\@gostorganizatiatext{#2}\relax}%
  \else%
    \gdef\gostorganizatiaopt{logo}%
    \def\gostorganizatialogo#2{\gdef\@gostorganizatialogo{#2}\relax}%
  \fi%
}
```

And in another `ESKD_frames.sty` style file:

```
\ifx \gostorganizatiaopt text%
  \spformedboxmm{135}{20}{185}{4.0}{s}{\@gostorganizatiatext}%
\else%
  \spformedboxmm{150}{16}{170}{4.0}{s}{\includegraphics*[keepaspectratio=true, height=10mm]{\@gostorganizatialogo}}%
\fi%
```

Macro `spformedboxmm` draw `#6` argument between x1-x2 and y1,y2 with parameter `s`.

Usage in a `title.tex`:

```
\gostorganizatia{1}{some text}% for drawing text
```

or to draw float figure

```
\gostorganizatia{2}{./path_to_logo.jpg}
```

What is the best way to define global variable to use it in a different `*.sty` files?

Update:

In a `main.log` there are few error:

**! Undefined control sequence.  ...age  LaTeX Error: File `\@gostorganizatialogo ' not found.**
and **! LaTeX Error: File`' not found.**

It seems to me that `\gostorganizatiaopt` does not work.

Comment: your question is not very clear, what do you need to define? After `\newcommand{\gostorganizatia}[2]` the macro takes two arguments so the use should be  `\gostorganizatia{1}{some text}` not `\gostorganizatia{1, some text}`  note also you are missing `%` from ends of lines in the definition `\gdef\@gostorganizatiaoption{1}` should be `\gdef\@gostorganizatiaoption{1}%` and same for `{2}`

Comment: Ok, I'll check it, maybe it's my syntax error

Comment: Also, asking a question of the form "What is the best way..." requests subjective input as there may be no best way, or different people think their own solution is *best*.

Answer (score 1):

You *think* that

```
\ifx \gostorganizatiaopt text%
```

test whether `\gostorganizatiaopt` is being compared to `text`. However, it's actually being compared to `t`, and it will never be true in your case. If you want a text-comparison, use the e-TeX `\pdfstrcmp{<strA>}{<strB>}` which returns 0 if `<strA>` = `<strB>`:

```
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\gostorganizatiaopt}{text}=0
  % TRUE <text>
\else
  % FALSE <logo>
\fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A [counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters) is the best way for me.

In the `eskdi.sty` file declare macro

```
\newcounter{gostorgcounter}% 0=text; 1=logo
\newcommand{\gostorganizatia}[2]{%
  %
  \setcounter{gostorgcounter}{#1}%
  %
  \ifnum\thegostorgcounter=0% 0 - text; 1 - logo
    \newcommand{\gostorganizatiatext}[1]{#2}
  \fi%
  %
  \ifnum\thegostorgcounter=1%
    \newcommand{\gostorganizatialogo}[1]{#2}
  \fi%
}%
```

In a drawing file the follow construction:

```
\ifnum\thegostorgcounter=0% text mode
  \spboxmm{125}{10}{170}{4.0}{lc}{\parbox{70mm}{\centering \gostorganizatiatext{}}}
\fi%
%
\ifnum\thegostorgcounter=1% logo mode
  \spformedboxmm{150}{10}{170}{4.0}{c}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true]{\gostorganizatialogo{}}}%
\fi%
```

Usage `\gostorganizatia{0}{some text}` for text mode or `\gostorganizatia{1}{./path_to_logo.jpg}` for image.